# Android wifi returns always Empty Scan Results(in API 25)

Tags: android, android-wifi

It didn't `crash` but my when I call the `getScanResults()` method it doesn't give me the Results.I got this:

```
2019-01-13 21:40:57.581 3647-3910/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=1104, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
```

i dont know what should i do pls help me

This is my Code

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Socket socket;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    Network network;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("TAG00","scanning");
            boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false);
            if(success) {
                Scan();
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        Scan();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        socket =new Socket();

        //Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        //  startActivity(myIntent);
        intentFilter=new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        wifiManager= (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<WifiConfiguration> x= wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for(WifiConfiguration a:x){
            // Log.i("TAG00",a.SSID);
            // Log.i("TAG00",a.BSSID);
            if(a.SSID.equals("MyNetwork"));
            wifiManager.startScan();

            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
        }



        for(Network n:connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()){

            NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(n);
            //   Log.i("TAG00",String.valueOf(networkInfo.getExtraInfo()));
            //   Log.i("TAG00",String.valueOf(networkInfo));

        }


    }
    public void WifiOn(View view){
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);


    }
    public void WifiOFF(View view){
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

    }
    public void Scan (){

        Log.i("TAG00","method called");

        ArrayList<ScanResult>results= new ArrayList<>( wifiManager.getScanResults());


        int data=results.size();
        Log.i("TAG00",String.valueOf(data));
        ArrayList<ScanResult> arrayList=new ArrayList<>(results);
        for(ScanResult scanResult:arrayList){
            Log.i("TAG00",String.valueOf(scanResult.SSID));

        }
    }
}
My Uses permissions:
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    enter code here
```